# Auto redirect to the login page after inactivity of user in yii2

Tags: session, yii2

I am trying to Auto-redirect the user after inactivity in the **`yii2`**.
I have added this to my configuration.
Currently, if the user stays inactive for 30 seconds and then clicks on any link in the application it will be redirected to the login.

But it should Auto Redirect to the login page after inactivity of 30 seconds automatically without a click on any other places in the application.

```
'session' => [
        'timeout' => 30,
 ],
'user' => [
        'class'=>'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'loginUrl'=>['site/login'],
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,                        
        'authTimeout' => 30,                   
    ],
```

I have tryied this in above code but it will gives 404 error.

```
'loginUrl'=> Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']),
```

So how should i redirect **automatically** after 30 second if **inactivity**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such direct way to do that, but you can achieve this in following way, please check:

(1) Add javascript code in views/site/main.php layout file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //call this function after 30 seconds or any time that you want to set.
        // as this code is in main.php layout so if user navigates to any screen this function sets again back to 30 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            // logout() method destroys all sessions
            <?php Yii::$app->user->logout(); ?>
            //and then just reload the page
            location.reload();
        }, 30000); // calling this function after 30 seconds
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add session timeout as well

```
'components' => [
...
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'enableSession' => true,
            'authTimeout' => 1800, //30 minutes
     ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
            'timeout' => 1800,
        ],
...
```

You can use **behaviors** for actions.

```
 public function behaviors()
 {
     return [
         'access' => [
             'class' => AccessControl::className(),
             'only' => ['index', 'logout','view','create','update','delete'],
             'rules' => [
                 [
                     'actions' => ['index', 'logout','view','create','update','delete'],
                     'allow' => true,
                     'roles' => ['@'],
                 ],
             ],
         ],
     ];
 }
```

So user is not logged in it will redirect to login url. You can also set login url

```
'session' => [
        'timeout' => 10,
      ],
'user' => [
      'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
      'enableAutoLogin' => false,
      'authTimeout' => 10,
      'loginUrl' => 'admin/default/login' // set your login path here
     ],
```

OR You can use **beforeAction** method to check that user is logged in or not and send user to login page.

```
 public function beforeAction($action){

        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->redirect(['site/login'])->send();  // login path
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this it will timeout the session but user needs to do (perform) any action to redirect themself to the login page.
The system did not automatically redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: The main issue here is the redirection in backend users get session out and everything but the user has to take any action to get redirect (or page needed to reload) to get logout.  @AmiteshKumar

Comment: check my  answer now

Comment: `beforeAction()` example is incorrect - `parent::beforeAction()` call is missing and `beforeAction()` does not work in this way (boolean should be returned, not response object).